# How to Click on pop up text using Robotium

Tags: robotium

I am getting an expected pop up, I know what text it will have and
what buttons will it have. I want to click on one of the buttons.

Once I get to the pop up screen, I see some text and 3 buttons. My
test passes if I use
             Solo.searchButton("Text") 
or
             Solo.searchText("Text").

The problem is when I do Solo.ClickOnButton ("Text") or
solo.clickOnText("Text").

I tried using solo.getViews(); but still
running into same error.

No button or text with "Text" is found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to overcome this by using solo.getView()

```
            View donebtn = solo.getView(R.id.pop_up_button);
            solo.clickOnView(donebtn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using longclick instead of just clickonbutton.
And is the message that pops up within the same package as your activity thats under test?